# PHP precision limitation

Tags: php

I'm having trouble about getting the exact value in PHP.

I have these values :

```
$a = 22900000.002827;
$b = 0.022900;

$c = $a/$b;
```

I'm expecting to have a result of `1000000000.12345` but it only return `1000000000.1234`

My question is that, is there any way to bypass this limitation in PHP?

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems ?

Comment: This isn't even valid php code. `$c = a/b;` must be `$c = $a/$b;`

Comment: @wumm actually this is syntactically correct :) - guess why

Comment: sorry for that. Forgot to add.

Comment: @birdspider Really? Why?

Comment: @wumm \*cough\*constants\*cough\*

Comment: @wumm a and b could be constants, `php -l` accepts that as beeing `No syntax errors detected in file.php` :)

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: @birdspider Ahh Yes, of course. I meant in this context its not correct.

Comment: Can you use [gpm](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) in your environment?

Comment: @wumm of course - I just wantet to point out that claiming `not valid php`, especially with php will sometimes suprise you

Comment: @sack Check BCMATCH extension http://ie1.php.net/bcmath This may solve your problem (I did not try)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's floating point numbers [are platform-dependent](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), however with the proper formatting print and on a 64bit build you should be able to get the desired result:

```
printf("%.5f", 22900000.002827 / 0.022900); 
// on my system, prints: 1000000000.12345
```

If you want to print "up to 5" decimal places, but with no tailing zeros it they are not needed you can use the `g` format type:

```
printf("%.5f", 1/2); 
// prints: 0.50000 - this is pretty ugly

printf("%.5g", 1/2); 
// prints: 0.5

printf("%.5g", 22900000.002827 / 0.022900); 
// prints: 1.0e+9 unfortunately

print rtrim(sprintf("%.5f", 22900000.002827 / 0.022900), "0");
print rtrim(sprintf("%.5f", 1/2), "0");
// prints: 1000000000.12345 and 0.5
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. My problem is that what if I changed my values and it will have only 4 decimal places?

Comment: The `%.5f` format string will always print 5 decimal places (padded with `0`s if needed), and as much numbers before the decimal point (`.`) as needed. Check out the formatting string docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for more info.

Comment: Added a new example for `g`, i had a hunch that you wanted this.

Comment: What if I use my first example? Does it still return 1000000000.12345 if I use the "g" format?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't (fixed in the answer too) since the `g` will use scientific notation for the 1000000000 and forgo about the decimals in that case. As far as i know there's no format string that both precise and short (this is actually a [pretty hard problem](http://kurtstephens.com/files/p372-steele.pdf). You could however use `rtrim()` to get rid of the zeros from `f`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [bcdiv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)  and supply no of digits what you want after `decimal` like

```
<?php 
 $a = 22900000.002827; 
 $b = 0.022900; 

 $c = $a/$b; 
 echo " c=".$c; 

 $d = bcdiv("$a", "$b", 5); 
 echo " d=".$d; 
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
c=1000000000.1234 
d=1000000000.12344
```

[**Demo**](http://3v4l.org/kqDav#v432)

Comment: what if I've tried different values and its exact decimal places is 4 only?

Comment: pass the value and see the output